# How can I check the size of my managed document/core data in code?

Tags: ios, core-data, uimanageddocument, cs193p

This question comes along as I'm doing one extra credit item for an assignment from the iTunes U Stanford cs193p course.

The assignment basically requires an app that downloads photos and stores some relevant information in database using core data. And this particular item asks to prune the database periodically.

What I want to do is check the size of my file every time the app is launched and if it crosses a certain threshold I'll do some clean-up. However I haven't find any way to actually check that size after looking around in the documentation about `UIManagedDocument` and `NSFileManager`.

Is there a way to check the size of a managed document? If so, how?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `[NSFileManager attributesOfFileAtPath:error:]` and then query `NSFileSize` from the returned dictionary.

Comment: @trojanfoe Is this the size of the particular managed document at the Path? since the size I just got using this method is surprisingly large.

Comment: Yes; it's the size of the file on disk.

Comment: NSFileSize is always in bytes, so you might think its so large...

Comment: @purplej0kr I translated that into MB and the result was close to 1GB. Later I cleaned up the data by deleting the app in the simulator and then launched again. The first time I got zero byte, which is fine. But the second time it surged to 984 MB and a similar result next time. Is there any default data being prepared for any app? FYI, I use core data model.

Comment: OK if you are using Core Data then you don't want to use `NSFileManager` which is for plain-files.  You will have to use an alternative method.

Comment: @trojanfoe What alternative could it be? Like what class may I refer to? Or is there a general way to do it?

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about Core Data.